# .NET 7 cookie authentication lost on restart / recycle

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-7.0

I have a .NET 7 web app in IIS that uses cookie authentication. Currently, any app recycle at all kicks the user off. This includes a website stop/start and code rebuild and deploy obviously.

I've gone through all the many questions for this scenario and I think I've got everything set up as it should be, but it is still doing it.

**Things I have done**

1. Changed `setProfileEnvironment`from `false` to `true` in `applicationHost.config` (and restarted IIS afterwards)
2. Explicity set cookie sliding expiration:

   ```
           options.SlidingExpiration = true;
           options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
   ```
3. Set persistence and absolute expiration:

   ```
           await HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
               CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
               principal,
               new AuthenticationProperties
               {
                   IsPersistent = true,
                   AllowRefresh = true,
                   ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7 * 4)
               }
           );
   ```
4. Added data protection before the `builder.Build()` call (although I'm not even sure this should be required if the user profile environment is set - the docs imply that .NET will manage it itself then?)

   ```
       var keysfolder = "_keys";

       var keyspath = Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, keysfolder);

       if (!Directory.Exists(keyspath))
           Directory.CreateDirectory(keyspath);

       services.AddDataProtection()
             .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keyspath))
             .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(7 * 4));
   ```

I have tried adding the data protection both before the `AddCookie` call and after it; no effect.

The user is still logged out on every recycle and every restart.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

In case this helps future me or anyone else, this was a real XY problem, because none of the above is relevant.

As the docs imply, for a single server cookie authenticated site you do not need data protection to persist cookies between restarts.

The problem was actually in some later code of my own that stored a static reference to the user; this was then used deep in some permission checking, but being lost and not repopulated correctly on recycle.

Comment: Isn't this by design with cookie authentication? The recycling of the app will invalidate the session...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DESIRED BEHAVIOUR**

Your requirement is a good one. Application recycling should not force users to re-authenticate, which would be considered a major problem in some use cases. Cookies should help to enable that. This may not be a complete answer but my answer may give you a few clues.

**DOT NET COOKIES**

The [Microsoft cookie issuing code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L290) is meant to be stateless by default, if no session store is configured. Therefore, when a cookie is received, the user ID and expiry time should be determined solely from the cookie in HTTP requests.

**IIS BEHAVIOUR**

I wonder if IIS is overriding the default .NET behaviour. I seem to remember an IIS setting something like `system.web/sessionState` that you could set to `Use Cookies` in the web configuration?

**COOKIE ENCRYPTION KEYS**

Cookies are encrypted using a symmetric encryption key. You usually need to override Microsoft's default implementation, eg in clustered setups. Yet you seem to be doing this  in a resilient way, so I doubt that is the issue. Still, I would focus very closely on capturing the HTTP request and response from a user browser after an `iisreset`. Is it definitely a cookie being rejected?

**SIMILAR PROJECT**

At Curity, where I work, we produced a related project a while back. It was a [utility API](https://github.com/curityio/oauth-agent-dotnet) to issue cookies for OAuth secured Single Page Apps in cloud native deployments.

The reason I mention it is that we wanted the same stateless and resilient cookie behaviour that you seem to want. Our requirements were met quite easily by the Kestrel web server.

So if you find nothing else you might do a spike that runs your web app in Kestrel. That would enable you to determine whether .NET or IIS is the source of your problems.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the assemblies (DLLs) of a ASP.NET Core web application hosted on IIS requires you stop and (re)start the application pool so those assemblies get unlocked and can be replaced.

Stop and (re)starting (or recycling) the application pool releases all memory allocated to the web application, effectively wiping out all session data. Consequently, previously logged in users have to re-login because cookie authentication is all about storing the user’s authentication information (i.e. the session ID) but that ID no longer exists.

*Assuming* the source of your problem is what I've described above, [Shadow Copying Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/shadow-copy-assemblies) has been introduced as a solution starting experimentally in [.NET 6](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/23733) and being fully supported in [.NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/25499).

I haven't tried shadow copying myself but I plan to do so as I am facing the same problem. Nevertheless, here's the (official) necessary configuration in `web.config` to enable it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".logsstdout">
      <handlerSettings>
        <handlerSetting name="enableShadowCopy" value="true" />
        <!-- Ensure that the IIS ApplicationPool identity has permission to this directory -->
        <handlerSetting name="shadowCopyDirectory" value="../ShadowCopyDirectory/" />
      </handlerSettings>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please, refer to the links I've provided above for assistance with fine tuning the configuration as per your needs.

*If*, on the other hand, your problem is about pool recycling in general (and not due to the update of assemblies in particular), then you should probably [read this comprehensive answer](https://serverfault.com/a/333948).

Comment: Hmmm, this is extremely useful for live sites in that it allows updating the files in one go without stopping/starting the site; however it then waits for the next recycle to update the shadow files so for development / fast releases it needs a restart anyway.

What is different about the Core (and later) model that makes this happen? I'm using cookie auth for many framework sites and the current user survives an apppool restart? The session doesn't but the auth data does.

Comment: @Whelkaholism If I am not mistaken, .NET Framework web application didn't have the same problem because previous versions of ASP.NET did some complicated shadow copying to work around the file locking problems. Related discussion can be read [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3793)

Comment: @Whelkaholism I've updated my answer to point you to an answer about how to configure pool recycling, in general. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I am not entirely certain if it is the same case, but I have observed a similar behavior in the past and resolved it by simply starting the ASP .NET State Service and configuring it to start automatically (or delayed).

[image: ASP.NET State Service screenshot]

Comment: Sadly that was not it 

Comment: This is related to .NET Framework, not to .NET Core